# Error when importing tensorflow probability on streamlit-cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, streamlit, requirements.txt, tensorflow-probability

I am new to the streamlit app environment.
I am trying to deploy my streamlit app onto streamlit-cloud using the deploy app functionality provided on the site(https://share.streamlit.io/). The app deploys , but throws an error while importing tensorflow-probability library . The error is as follows

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'compiler' from 'tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct' (/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/__init__.py)
```

This app seems to be working fine on my local machine. The contents of my requirements.txt file are as follows

```
matplotlib==3.5.0
numpy==1.21.5
pandas==1.3.5
scikit_learn==1.0.2
streamlit==1.5.0
tensorflow==2.2.0rc1
tensorflow_probability==0.8.0rc0
click==8.0.4
```

Should I add another library to mitigate this?
Should I change the version of the tensorflow-probability library?
I have also added a link to my Github project in case there is something wrong in the way that I have defined certain functions. The Python code is in the file **streamlit_app.py** (https://github.com/adhok/streamlit_ames_housing_price_prediction_app)

Thank You in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TF and TFP  versions are both pretty old, and both are "release candidates" (not final releases). All things equal, you should advance both versions to the most recent stable releases: tensorflow==2.8 and tensorflow-probability==0.16